# c# Populating a ListView from an XML File

Tags: c#, xml, listview

I am still learning my way around c# and am trying to populate my ListView from an XML file.

Below is a picture of my ListView:

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6aXO.png)

When I click a button on my UI, it reads the XML file using this code (Configuration.cs) here:

```
public static void LoadConfiguration(MainUI UIForm)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("E:\\InnerSpace" + "\\Scripts\\BJScripts\\MySettings.xml");

    MainUI uI = new MainUI();
    UIForm.addItemsToActionsListView(doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("Position_X").Value, doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("Position_Y").Value, doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("RGB").Value, doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("Is_Colour").Value, doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("Target").Value, doc.Element("UABA").Element("Configure_Tab").Element("Actions_List").Element("ListItem_1").Attribute("Press_Button").Value);
}
```

Then it calls a method in my MainUI.cs and passes the relevant information I need to it.

```
public partial class MainUI : Form
{

    public MainUI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void MainUI_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Program._bMustShutdown = true;
    }

    public void NewActionsConsoleMessage(string Input)
    {
        ActionsConsole.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") + ": " + Input);
        ActionsConsole.SelectedIndex = (ActionsConsole.Items.Count - 1);
    }

    private void btnAddAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtboxLocationX.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Enter a value for Position X and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for Position X and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (txtboxLocationY.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Enter a value for Position Y and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for Position Y and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (txtboxColourRGB.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Enter a value for Pixel RGB and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for Pixel RGB and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (!radionbtnIsColour.Checked && !radionbtnIsNotColour.Checked)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Select either tracking by colour or tracking my not colour and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Select either tracking by colour or tracking my not colour and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (cboxTarget.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Select a target and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Select a target and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        if (txtboxActionBtn.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            NewActionsConsoleMessage("ERROR: Enter a value for Action to Take Button Press and try again.");
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value for Action to Take Button Press and try again.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        ListViewItem addActionsItem = new ListViewItem(txtboxLocationX.Text);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(txtboxLocationY.Text);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(txtboxColourRGB.Text);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(radionbtnIsColour.Checked.ToString());
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(cboxTarget.Text);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(txtboxActionBtn.Text);
        lvActionsList.Items.Add(addActionsItem);
    }

    private void btnSetPixelLocationColour_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pixelColourPickerUI = new PixelColourPickerUI();
        pixelColourPickerUI.ShowDialog();

        txtboxLocationX.Text = pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelMouseLocX;
        txtboxLocationY.Text = pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelMouseLocY;
        txtboxColourRGB.Text = pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_R + "," + pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_G + "," + pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_B;
        pnlConfigurePixelColour.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_A, pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_R, pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_G, pixelColourPickerUI._SelectedPixelColor_B);
    }       

    public ListView.ListViewItemCollection listViewItemCollection
    {
        get { return lvActionsList.Items; }
    }

    public void addItemsToActionsListView(string _LocX, string _LocY, string _RGB, string _IsColour, string _Target, string _ButtonPress)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("_LocX: " + _LocX + "_LocY" + _LocY + "_RGB" + _RGB + "_IsColour" + _IsColour + "_Target" + _Target + "_ButtonPress" + _ButtonPress);

        ListViewItem addActionsItem = new ListViewItem(_LocX);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(_LocY);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(_RGB);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(_IsColour);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(_Target);
        addActionsItem.SubItems.Add(_ButtonPress);
        Debug.WriteLine("Count: " + addActionsItem.SubItems.Count);
        lvActionsList.Items.Add(addActionsItem);
    }

    private void btnSaveActionsList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration.Configuration.SaveConfiguration(items: lvActionsList.Items);
    }

    private void btnLoadProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration.Configuration.LoadConfiguration(this);
    }
}
```

The first Debug.WriteLine returns the proper passed variables from Configuration.cs and the second Debug.WriteLine returns the proper count of 6 SubItems.

However, when viewing my ListView, it is still empty. Previously, I was able to add the the ListView using identical code (with different variables) when I was making what eventually became the XML file information. What am I doing wrong when trying to load the information from the XML? Do you need to see more code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have declared in the method: LoadConfigutation, the variable ui as new. This is only in scope of that method. You need to refer to you list in the ui.

Comment: @Aldert Thanks for your response.

When I modify Configuration.cs by removing MainUI uI = new MainUI(); and change uI.addItemsToActionsListView(...) to MainUI.addItemsToActionsListView(...) I get an error message that says: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainUI.addItemsToActionsListView'.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Can you please enhance your code to show also the form class. We need this info to be able to support you.

Comment: Yes, I’ll be able to do this on Thursday as I am currently travelling and don’t have access to my computer.

Comment: @Aldert I'm back from travelling and have updated MainUI.cs as requested. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: In your static method LoadConfiguration you instanciate teh MainUI. So as soon you are out of the method, this object is gone. I understand why you do not see anything in your list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the MainUI as argument to your static method:

```
public static void LoadConfiguration(MainUI UiForm)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("E:\\InnerSpace" + "\\Scripts\\BJScripts\\MySettings.xml");

    UiForm.addItemsToActionsListView(doc.Element("UABA" etc
}
```